# Egit plugin file download

Tags: egit

We want to integrate EGIT plugin to our current eclipse android project. But could not able to get such plugin software from "http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/" and also not found any other download site for getting software any way. I need urgent to start working with EGIT plugin to manage the project between our team member. Please suggest how to get EGIT plugin asap.Thanks in advance for help / answer.

Comment: Are you using http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates as an update site URL from Eclipse or looking to download the plugins as a zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the url for git for eclipse:

"Eclipse EGit updates - latest release - Composite P2 Repository" - http://www.jgit.org/updates

Answer (score 0):

In your Eclipse IDE, go to Help>Install New Software
and add this link to the "work with:" form and click add. then click next until finished

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.3

then follow the instructions here

http://wangpidong.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/how-to-use-bitbucket-with-egit-in.html

hope this helps you. :)